# Kafka read MyClacc

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I can’t write the data to the parquet file from the kafka. I am trying to convert data from kafka to Dataset  (r1). The schema returns correctly, but the data is all null. I can’t understand where the error is. 
Sample data:
{"time":100000000000,"quantity":3000,"orderNo":16545,"realOrderNo":19022241346,"clientcodeid":9411494,"entryTime":95003618770,"price":0.4904,"firm":"0000500000","boardid":"00000F00","seccode":"00000F00","trdaccid":"00000F00","buysell":"B","marketMaker":false,"initialQuantity":3000,"tradedate":"17.12.2019"}
I can’t understand why the data is not returned. 
Help me please.

```
    StructType schema = new StructType()
            .add("time","int")
            .add("quantity","long")
            .add("orderNo","long")
            .add("realOrderNo","long")
            .add("clientcodeid","long")
            .add("entryTime","long")
            .add("price","long")
            .add("firm","String")
            .add("boardid","String")
            .add("seccode","String")
            .add("trdaccid","String")
            .add("buysell","String")
            .add("marketMaker","boolean")
            .add("initialQuantity","long")
            .add("tradedate","String")
            ;

    r1 =  sqlContext
            .read()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", IKafkaConstants.KAFKA_BROKERS)
            .option("subscribe", IKafkaConstants.TOPIC_NAME)
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint/1")
            .load()
            .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
            .select(functions.from_json(col("value"), schema).as("data"))

    ;


    System.out.println("r1");
    r1.printSchema();
    r1.show();
```

Result:

```
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- time: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- quantity: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- orderNo: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- realOrderNo: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- clientcodeid: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- entryTime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- price: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firm: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- boardid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- seccode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- trdaccid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- buysell: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- marketMaker: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- initialQuantity: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tradedate: string (nullable = true)

+----+
|data|
+----+
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

In schema, two field types do not corresponds with JSON values, such types have to be used:

```
.add("time","long")
.add("price","double")
```